# Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName. error

Tags: google-bigquery

Application: Connecting to BigQuery using BigQuery APIs for Java
Environment: Eclipse, Windows 7

My application was running fine until last night. I've made no changes (except for restarting my computer) and my code is suddenly giving me this error:

```
Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
```

Thankfully I had a tar'd version of my workspace from last night. I ran a folder compare and found the local_db.bin file was different. I deleted the existing local_db.bin file and tried to run the program again. And it worked fine!

Any idea why this might have happened?

Hopefully this will help anyone else who stumbles upon this issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this to set your application name

```
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                  .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
                  .setApplicationName("Your app name")
                  .build();
```

Comment: it would be great if someone explains... what this "APP NAME" use for and how it affect to app...

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with only Firebase Dynamic Links without Android or iOS app

Try this.
    builder.setApplicationName(firebaseUtil.getApplicationName());

FirebaseUtil is custom class add keys and application name to this class

```java
FirebaseDynamicLinks.Builder builder = new FirebaseDynamicLinks.Builder(
                    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null);

    // initialize with api key
FirebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer firebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer = new FirebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer(
                    firebaseUtil.getFirebaseApiKey());
builder.setFirebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer(firebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer);
builder.setApplicationName(firebaseUtil.getApplicationName());
// build dynamic links
FirebaseDynamicLinks firebasedynamiclinks = builder.build();

// create Firebase Dynamic Links request
CreateShortDynamicLinkRequest createShortLinkRequest = new CreateShortDynamicLinkRequest();
            createShortLinkRequest.setLongDynamicLink(firebaseUtil.getFirebaseUrlPrefix() + "?link=" + urlToShorten);
Suffix suffix = new Suffix();
suffix.setOption(firebaseUtil.getShortSuffixOption());
createShortLinkRequest.setSuffix(suffix);

// request short url
FirebaseDynamicLinks.ShortLinks.Create request = firebasedynamiclinks.shortLinks()
                    .create(createShortLinkRequest);
CreateShortDynamicLinkResponse createShortDynamicLinkResponse = request.execute();
```