# Google Drive Authorization Error with Unity 3D plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-oauth, google-drive-api

I've got a Problem with the Google Drive service for an Android App.
It's an Unity 3D project which includes a Plugin to use the Google Drive API https://github.com/midworld/unity-googledrive

I used the plugin already on PC builds and it works fine. The Oauth2 authorization works, I get a working Token, and I can write, delete, download, etc. files from the Google Drive of the logged in google user account. On PC the plugin uses web requests to comunicate with google drive.

But when I try to use the plugin on an Android device I can't authorize and get an Oauth2 token from the google service. On Android devices the Plugin uses the google drive API. 
I think the error is rooted in my Manifest.xml, since I am still not sure what exactly it should contain.

The Error Messages:

```
I/Unity   (17269): Start Authorization
D/Unity-GoogleDrivePlugin(17269): setUnityActivity: com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity@423bbdd0
D/Unity-GoogleDrivePlugin(17269): auth with accountName: dino******@******.com
W/AbstractGoogleClient(17269): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
D/Unity-GoogleDrivePlugin(17269): google drive service: com.google.api.services.drive.Drive@423aa280
W/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: unable to resolve static field 634 (auth_client_play_services_err_notification_msg) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x001a
I/dalvikvm(17269): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x027b at 0x42 in Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;.a
I/dalvikvm(17269): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0279 at 0x4d in Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;.a
W/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: unable to resolve static field 642 (common_google_play_services_install_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0041
W/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: unable to resolve static field 638 (common_google_play_services_enable_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x004c
W/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: unable to resolve static field 648 (common_google_play_services_update_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0057
W/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: unable to resolve static field 645 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0069
W/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: unable to resolve static field 639 (common_google_play_services_install_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0009
W/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: unable to resolve static field 636 (common_google_play_services_enable_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0010
W/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: unable to resolve static field 646 (common_google_play_services_update_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0017
W/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: unable to resolve static field 643 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm(17269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm(17269): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0281 at 0x18 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.c
I/dalvikvm(17269): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0280 at 0x38 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.c
I/dalvikvm(17269): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x027d at 0x3f in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.c
I/dalvikvm(17269): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0287 at 0x46 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.c
I/dalvikvm(17269): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0284 at 0x66 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.c
W/GLSUser ( 5447): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
W/GLSActivity( 5447): [art] Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
W/GLSActivity( 5447): [art] Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
I/GLSUser ( 5447): GLS error: INVALID_KEY dino******@******.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
W/GLSActivity( 5447): [art] Status from wire: Unknown status: UNKNOWN
E/Unity-GoogleDrivePlugin(17269): checkAuthorized: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
I/Unity   (17269): GoogleDrive+Exception: Authorization failed.
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    package="com.studio272.unitydrivetest" 
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:versionCode="1">

  <supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />

  <application 
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="false">

    <activity 
        android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="behind" 
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.studio272.googledriveplugin.GoogleDrivePluginActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=318737920467" />
    </activity>
  </application>

  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251189/application-name-is-not-set-call-buildersetapplicationname-error

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. 
In unity 3D I also have to say what keystore and Bundle Unity should use to sign my apk file.

So under "Edit -> Project Settings -> Player" then in the section for "Android -> Publishing Settings" I had to brows to the keystore I am using and enter the password for the keystore. Also pick the "alias" and enter the password again

Furthermore in the "Android Section -> other settings"  I had to set the "Bundle Identifier" to my package name from the google developer console.

now the Authentification with the OAuth2 token works and I can work with the google drive.